# DEC Fortran Compiler?

Tags: fortran

I've been provided with a *very* large bank of code which I need to be able to adjust, compile, and run. After some fiddling and attempts, I've deduced that the code was written with DEC standards. gfortran (version 5.4.0, running on Linux Mint / Ubuntu) does not seem able to compile it smoothly, and the -fdec command line option does not appear to be recognized. I started trying to update the code (replacing ACCEPT with READ, etc) but the task is rather daunting - especially since every step is preceded by 30 minutes of research to find the fix.

The provider of said code used PGF77. As far as I can tell, this is not a compiler I can get for free. Are there other, free compilers that can do a comparable job? Alternatively, can I get gfortran -fdec to work somehow?

Comment: The Intel Fortran compiler is a lineal descendant of the DEC compiler.  Whether you can get that without paying for it, I don't know.

Comment: If you have an old gfortran which doesn't accept fdec, time to upgrade.

Comment: This site is not or recommending compilers, but if you use your favourite web search engine  you should find a PGI compiler for free easily (hint: try their website and github). Also you can easily upgrade your gfortran.

Comment: I recommend Intel for this. You can obtain it for free if for non-commercial use, see here: https://software.intel.com/en-us/qualify-for-free-software.

Comment: Intel no longer offers free non-commercial compilers except to students at certain schools and to "open source contributors". The "Performance Libraries" download, which is free, does not contain compilers.

Comment: You have two choices :
1. Upgrade your gfortran compiler to a newer version (>=7.1).
2. Download Free [PGI Community Edition](http://www.pgroup.com/products/community.htm) ( Which includes pgfortran and pgf77 ).

Answer (score 2):

**`gfortran` version 7 or later supports `-fdec` option. https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-7/**

---

#### option 1 - GNU `gfortran`

GNU compiler collection as of version 7 supports (released around 2018) the "-fdec" option. So go get `gfortran` from GCC version 7 or later or most recent. https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-7/

#### option 2 - Intel `ifort`

Also an option but more of a hassle is to get the Intel compiler `ifort` which has supported the DEC extensions to fortran for many years. Intel's compiler is more of a hassle because of it is proprietary and costs money (hundreds of $ or more) and requires managing licenses.

Comment: also apparently there is a free version of pgf77 according to the comments above.

Comment: Not only has ifort supported it for many years, it is the direct descendant of DEC (later Compaq) Fortran. Anyway, the quetion is IMO off-topic and should have been closed. That is also why a previous answer here was later deleted by the answere and why other people left only comments.

Comment: @VladimirF re offtopic. yes. i agree the question is offtopic. still helpful tho.